Twilight Imperium: Can you use flagship's space cannon against ships in an adjacent system?
This feels like something that has been asked but I can't find it.
In Twilight Imperium, if I move the Xxacha flagship into an active system, could I then use its space cannon against ships in an adjacent system?
The relevant ability on the Flagship is:

You may use this unit's SPACE CANNON against ships that are in adjacent systems.
Space Cannon 5 (x3)

E.g. Sol has a carrier in Mecatol Rex, could I then move my flagship into a system adjacent to Mecatol Rex and then use my space cannon ability against their carrier in the Mecatol Rex system?

Not exactly, with space cannon you can only target units in the active system. If you move the flagship to a system, you can not shoot space cannon to an adjacent system as it is not the active one. However, you can activate a system adjacent to your flagship and shoot your space cannon without moving any ship.

Good answer.  Would be better with citations from the rulebook

Yes, you could if – according to the Twilight Imperium Wiki:

you have the PDS II unit upgrade "Deep Space Cannon".


If a player has the PDS II unit upgrade technology, they can use the
“Space Cannon” ability of their PDS units that are in systems that are
adjacent to the active system (Deep Space Cannon). The hits are still
assigned to units in the active system.


You have the right rules quote but the wrong conclusion.  The key piece of that rules is that you can only resolve space cannons against units in the active system

Additionally, the Xxacha flagship does not need the PDS II upgrade to target adjacent systems; By default, it essentially acts as 3 PDSIIs, even without the upgrade.
